# MYSQL: UPDATE FROM INNER JOIN syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to update `TableA` with values from `TableB`, matched by the unique `id` field and add a `WHERE` condition.
Searched the web and found the code below. For some reason MYSQL states that there's as syntax error.

```
UPDATE
    TableA
SET
    TableA.field1 = TableB.field1
FROM
    TableA
INNER JOIN
    TableB
ON
    TableA.id = TableB.id
WHERE
    TableA.field1 <> ''
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE TableA INNER JOIN
       TableB
       ON TableA.id = TableB.id
    SET TableA.field1 = TableB.field1
WHERE TableA.field1 <> '';
```

As a note:  you cannot use `LIMIT` with a `JOIN`.

If you want to use `LIMIT`, you can do:

```
UPDATE TableA 
    SET TableA.field1 = (SELECT TableB.field1 FROM TableB WHERE TableA.id = TableB.id)
    WHERE TableA.field1 <> '' AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB WHERE TableA.id = TableB.id)
    LIMIT 100;
```

(You can leave out the `EXISTS` expression if you know there is always a match in `TableB`.  You can add `LIMIT 1` to the subquery if more than one match is possible.)

I would advise you to always use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT` as well.  That way, you can control which rows are being updated.